# How to handle decimals in excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007, excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel worksheet concerning site data and trying to transfer this to a Site_Table in an Access database (Office 2007).  I can get everything to transfer except two columns that are the site geographical coordinates.

This first example works fine where I loop through the worksheet rows;

```
For i = 2 To numSheetRows
strSearchMatch = ws.Cells(i, n).Value

If Len(strSearchMatch) <> 0 Then

intSearchMatch = CLng(strSearchMatch)

  With adoRecSet
  .Open "Select UPRN, Site_Name, Site_Address, Site_Category, Site_VMB,   
  Site_Retain_WAN " & _
  "FROM Site_Table WHERE Site_Id = " & intSearchMatch & ";", _
     connDB, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
   .Fields("UPRN").Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
   .Fields("Site_Name").Value = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
   .Fields("Site_Address").Value = ws.Cells(i, 17).Value
   .Fields("Site_Category").Value = ws.Cells(i, 15).Value
   .Fields("Site_VMB").Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
   .Fields("Site_Retain_WAN").Value = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value
   .Update
   .Close
  End With
 End If
Next i
```

But I need to include the columns for X and Y coordinates.  What is confusing me is that the relevant columns are formatted to type "General", but the cell highlighted in the image below has this value in the formula bar of 245946.693280609.

[image]

I have tried converting the value to a decimal with "CDec" and using a variant.  In the database I have the field set as a Decimal to 4 decimal places but when I try to enter the xcoord value as shown in the example below I receive the error "Scaling of decimal value resulted in data truncation".  I can change the database field to text and it works, but basically how do I get the values from the worksheet to the database in the way they are shown in the spreadsheet?

```
For i = 2 To numSheetRows
strSearchMatch = ws.Cells(i, n).Value

If Len(strSearchMatch) <> 0 Then

intSearchMatch = CLng(strSearchMatch)

  With adoRecSet
  .Open "Select UPRN, Site_Name, Site_Address, Site_Category, Site_VMB,   
  Site_Retain_WAN, Site_X_Coord " & _
  "FROM Site_Table WHERE Site_Id = " & intSearchMatch & ";", _
     connDB, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
   .Fields("UPRN").Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
   .Fields("Site_Name").Value = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
   .Fields("Site_Address").Value = ws.Cells(i, 17).Value
   .Fields("Site_Category").Value = ws.Cells(i, 15).Value
   .Fields("Site_VMB").Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
   .Fields("Site_Retain_WAN").Value = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value
   .Fields("Site_X_Coord").Value = ws.Cells(i, 23).Value
   .Update
   .Close
  End With
 End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJF,

Maybe this will work you, if you use  ws.Cells(i, 23).**Text** instead of Cells(i.23).Value.

Eg.:
A1 = 100/33 (3,0303030303030303030303...)

Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.0000"
MsgBox "Value is " & Cells(2, 4).Text

[Msgbox with formatted value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmoox.jpg)